# Python Win32 can't read outlook email body's

Tags: python, email, winapi, outlook, message

Im trying to use win32 module for python and get the body of my email message. However whenever I try to get it i get an error for any email body I try to get. I am able to get the message subject/timerecieved/etc however I just can't seem to get the body.

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
body_content = message.body

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
com_error                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-bdd6c5734297> in <module>()
      1 messages = inbox.Items
      2 message = messages.GetLast()
----> 3 body_content = message.body#.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
      4 #print (body_content)

C:\Users\e659383\Documents\portableapps\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py in __getattr__(self, attr)
    509                         debug_attr_print("Getting property Id 0x%x from OLE object" % retEntry.dispid)
    510                         try:
--> 511                                 ret = self._oleobj_.Invoke(retEntry.dispid,0,invoke_type,1)
    512                         except pythoncom.com_error as details:
    513                                 if details.hresult in ERRORS_BAD_CONTEXT:

com_error: (-2147467259, 'Unspecified error', None, None)
```

I get same error for any email message I try to get the body.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure, but perhaps body should use a capital B as it seems to be referencing a C# property.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.body.aspx

So:
`body_content = message.Body`

Comment: Do you have an antivirus? -2147467259 translates to error code: 0x80004005. Which could be caused by anti-virus script-blocking features.

Comment: Hmm, we do have Mcaffee installed. Seems odd that it can specifically block getting the body of a message. But I guess it might make sense since I created a quick vb script to try and get the messages and it won't work either...

Comment: I agree that would be odd. Perhaps you could temporarily disable the anti-virus to see if that is your problem?