# How to remove everything after a certain keyword from email body using regex?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, win32com

I wrote the below code to grab specific values. They include date, index value: SGEPSBSH, and bbg level from a particular email.

I'm trying to save it to pandas dataframe. Before saving the entire email body to dataframe, I am trying to remove everything after client signature starting from keyword "Regards".

I get the following error:

```
File "snapper.py", line 39, in <module>
    Body_content = message.body
File "__init__.py", line 473, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (repr(self), attr))
AttributeError: '<Library._MailItem instance at 0x2473706520480>' 
                object has no attribute 'body'
```

Can you please help to fix my code?

```
import win32com.client
import re
import os
import pandas
import datetime
from datetime import date

EMAIL_ACCOUNT = 'atul.sanwal@ihsmarkit.com'
EMAIL_SUBJ_SEARCH_STRING = 'SGEPSBSH Index Level'
EMAIL_CONTNT = {'Ticker': [], 'TickerLevel': [], 'DATE': []}
out_app = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")
out_namespace = out_app.GetNamespace("MAPI")

root_folder = out_namespace.GetDefaultFolder(6)
out_iter_folder = root_folder.Folders['Email_snapper']
char_length_of_search_substring = len(EMAIL_SUBJ_SEARCH_STRING)
item_count = out_iter_folder.Items.Count
Flag = False
cnt = 0
if out_iter_folder.Items.Count > 0:
    for i in range(item_count, 0, -1)[:2]:
        message = out_iter_folder.Items[i]
        #message = message.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + lastWeekDateTime + "'")
Body_content = message.body
message.body = re.sub(r".*Regards[^\n]+\n[^\n]+", "",message.body)
print(Body_content)
```

[image]

Comment: Reading the question with a little more attention, the issue could be the lower case "b" in the attribute access, try using capital "B" in `message.Body` instead. Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41367241/python-win32-cant-read-outlook-email-bodys. Microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.body?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=outlook-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Outlook__MailItem_Body

Comment: i tried changing message.body to message.Body it did work but not serving the intended purpose

Comment: i mean the following line message.Body = re.sub(r".*Regards[^\n]+\n[^\n]+", "",message.Body) is only removing regards, and its next line

Comment: Did you try using slicing as I suggested in my answer below? If it is not working, please include a sample of the `message.Body` as text, since debugging without a sample is quite difficult.

Comment: i did try this  message.body = s[:s.find("Regards")].strip()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not set on using regex, a simple string slicing might work for you as well

```
s = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus tincidunt elit in ex " \
    "molestie euismod sed et velit. Aenean blandit placerat sodales. Curabitur mattis nibh nec " \
    "leo hendrerit commodo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eu " \
    "mattis dui, at convallis dolor."
s = s[:s.find("amet")].strip()
print(s)
```

Out:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit
```

Comment: like the below

message.body = s[:s.find("Regards")].strip()

Comment: @RahulVaidya Did it work or not (and why if it didn't)?

Comment: it says name 's' is not defined

Comment: i made the changes and it worked

Comment: can you also help to retrieve specific values from this like date, index price

Comment: Hello,
Please find bellow the level of SGEPSBSH Index as of 01-06-2022


 BBG Level  
2022-06-01  111.9852

Comment: @RahulVaidya Please ask a new question for that